# Need max length of a word output

Tags: python, output, max

```
def report_stat(word_dict):
    max_word = max(word_dict, key = word_dict.get)
    print('Longest word is:', max_word)

    # getting sorted list of word dict by value and printing 5 most common
    print('Five most common words are:')
    counter = 1
    for each_list in sorted(word_dict.items(),
        key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
        # printing the 5 most commonly used words
        if counter > 5:
            break
        print(each_list[0], each_list[1])
        counter += 1

    # opening the file out.xt in write mode
    #and writing word and their count sorted alphabetically
    with open('out.txt', 'w') as fp:
        for each_word in sorted(word_dict):
            print(each_word, word_dict[each_word], file=fp)
```

---

The area I'm getting wrong is the `Longest word is: the` shown below.

It is printing the most-used word, not the longest word.

```
Enter the filename: pride.txt
Longest word is: the
Five most common words are:
the 4322
to 4126
of 3596
and 3531
her 2181
```

Comment: Do you have an example `word_dict`? ([mcve])

Comment: Well yeah, it's printing the most used word because the key you use is (presumably) the frequency.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the longest word, the key function should make use of [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len):

```
max_word = max(word_dict, key=len)
```

which would be the same as:

```
max_word = max(word_dict, key=lambda x: len(x))
```

The way you are using `max()` would give you the last word in lexicographic order.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: because that makes a better example in general

Comment: @papercutbut: On this site, show your appreciation by upvoting all the useful answers. You do that by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer, if you have enough reputation to do so (but you don't, yet). In addition, accept the best answer (if it actually answers your question) by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment. It also helps others to see that your question was answered.

Comment: @papercutbut If you accept the answer, that counts, AFAIK.

Comment: @fferri It really doesn't. Wrapping a function in `lambda` for no reason at all is just silly. If you want to demonstrate proper use of anonymous functions make an example where using them makes sense.